# std::filesystem's parent_path() is wrong for file in current directory?

Tags: c++, c++17, std-filesystem

The traditional Unix shell utility, `dirname`, finds the name of the directory that contains the given file. This is useful if you want to find other sister files in the same directory. Here are a few examples:

```
$ dirname /some/dir/filename
/some/dir
$ dirname dirname/filename  
dirname
$ dirname filename
.
```

The new C++ std::filesystem's `parent_path()` gets this last one wrong (or so it appears):

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "parent of filename: " <<
        std::filesystem::path("filename").parent_path() << '\n';
}
```

outputs:

```
parent of filename: ""
```

Returning an empty string instead of "." is not only different from the traditional `dirname`, it's also wrong when used in code which wants to tack on a "/..." on this parent to create the name of a sister files - this results in the wrong "/sister" instead of expected "./sister".

Is this a bug in std::filesystem, or deliberate behavior? Is the reason for this behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: gcc and libstdc++ 13.2.1.

Comment: Concerning your question about documentation, see cppreference.com.

Comment: Ulrich, I don't see anything relevant to my question in the short https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/parent_path
They don't cover this case in the text or example, let alone try to explain why it behaves this way which is what I wanted to know now (I already know *how* it behaves, but not why).

Comment: I see. Concerning the discussion that lead to this behaviour, you could try to find meeting notes from the ISO council that lead to this behaviour. Yes, it's not a fruitful endeavour...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I won't argue with you whether this is correct or not, but if you always use [`std::filesystem::operator/`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/operator_slash) instead of doing string manipulation, I don't see how you will run into the issue you mention in the question.

In particular, `std::filesystem::path("filename").parent_path()/std::filesystem::path("filename")` gives you just `"filename"`, not `"/filename"`. I believe this is how the API is supposed to be used.

Comment: The RHS of `operator/` can be a simple string literal, no need to create a `path` instance from it first: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/append.

Comment: Yes. but in more complex cases you want to a more complex path in the end and then that should definitely be a `path` object, not some `string` containing slashes.

Answer (score 3):

Using `std::filesystem::path::parent_path`, the result is based on the value passed to `std::filesystem::path`. This function is only meant to make some simple parsing and not to resolve any path.

Globaly `std::filesystem::path` is, as the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) describe it, a representation of a path. If you wan't to have the same behavior as `dirname`, you need to look for other function available in `std::filesystem` namespace and build your own custom tool.

**Edit**:

The use of "simple" to describe the parsing strategy, mean it doesn't verify the actual value of what is parse, as the description of the function [`parent_path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/parent_path):

> If has_relative_path() returns false, the result is a copy of *this. Otherwise, the result is a path whose generic format pathname is the longest prefix of the generic format pathname of *this that produces one fewer element in its iteration.

Even if it's not explicit enought (for me at least), after a few tests, the **produces one fewer element in its iteration** sentence translate to: **produces a path to the previous directory-separators without any path resolution**.

Comment: dirname also doesn't do any sophisticated filesystem lookups and does only simple textual parsing. E.g., `dirname /a/b/../c/x` returns `/a/b/../c` and doesn't try to "canonize" it in any way. It's just the behavior for a file in the current directory which is different - and looks to me non-useful (it broke my application), so I was wondering if it's intentional and if so why.

Comment: I update the respond, with a more accurate parsing strategy explanation. For the part of why is it made this way, it's only a guess, but I think this is to have some flexibility in the resolution from the other function in the `std::filesystem` namespace.

Comment: DipStax thanks for the edit. I guess that description really fits what the function does today, but doesn't explain why it does it: If the given path has a single component, a file in the current directory: "filename", then the output will be a path with zero components. Right. But why is this useful? This is *not* the true parent directory. The true parent directory is ".", which also has one component, not zero.

Comment: The return of an empty string is certainly due of `.` being actually a file that contain the information about the actual directory. A directory is always represented by a `/`, for example if I use `/.`: this is a correct path because `/` represent the actual directory "position" and `.` is only the information file of the directory `/`.

Comment: So to keep the **produces a path to the previous directory-separators without any path resolution**, you can't give an other file as result (in the case the entry is "filename").